# Does "mouse" need an article in front of it?

Tags: definite-article

I have the following sentence:

> These elements are highlighted as **mouse** moves over them to make it easy for the user to detect the boundary of each element.

I thought I am addressing the mouse which is used by the user or is known for the reader because each computer has a mouse. I don't know if it needs "the" or not.

What is the rule here? If it doesn't need "the", why?

Comment: "mouse" is singular (pl. mice), and a group of them would also be mice. So "mouse" needs an article.

Comment: In short, yes, you need 'the mouse' here, using the because there is almost never more than one mouse cursor on a computer screen.

Comment: Technically, you could also use "your mouse"... or "the user's mouse" but these may be odd considering the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Short Answer: Yes, you do need to use "the".

Comment: Does this sentence match the situation mentioned [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67670/67196)?

Answer (score 1):

When you drop the article like that it's called the "zero article" if you want to read more about it. The general rule is that you can drop the article with mass nouns (e.g., bread, coffee) or plural nouns. There are a few other specific contexts where it applies, but this isn't one of them. You have a single mouse, so you need a "the".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article